# Start JBOSS using putty

Tags: linux, jboss

I am trying to run JBOSS using putty, I used this command

```
 ./standalone.sh -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 &
```

but when close the putty, server is closing down

please help

Comment: So what do you expect it to do when you kill the process that's running JBoss? Think of it this way, you are reading this post on a browser client and if you close the browser client you can't read it :). Also using a bind address of `0.0.0.0` is a bad idea in my opinion since it binds it to all network interfaces.

Comment: @CoolBeans
I said in the question, when kill putty process, JBoss process will be killed, if you have something to help please add

Comment: I think I already did :).

Comment: @CoolBeans how you did?

Comment: When you kill the parent process (putty) the child process dies (jboss). If you do not understand this, then I am not sure how else to explain it. If you want JBoss to keep running after closing your putty terminal, you need to look into OS level options such as nohup and running a process in background.

Comment: I understand your point, but I want to run JBOSS tell me how? I know if kill parent process the child will be killed

Comment: Start with nohup as a background would be one of the options. I already mentioned that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no problem with your command, but make sure to add **&** at the end, try to run this command in **JBOSS** **`bin`** folder:

```
 ./standalone.sh &
```

so **`JBOSS`** will not be terminated when the putty is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `nohup`. This will prevent the JBOSS server being killed when you exit putty.

```
nohup ./standalone.sh -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 &
```